# Why Subversion skips files which contain the @ symbol?

Tags: file, svn, special-characters, revert

when I try to execute command like this (from a command-line or Perl script - it doesn't matter):

```
svn revert "build\myfile@test.meta"
```

SVN skips this file and outputs:

```
Skipped 'build\myfile'
```

I tried doing:

```
svn revert "build\*.meta"
```

But it gives the same result.

I can revert these files from the GUI. And I can revert these files by doing (but it reverts more than I want):

```
svn revert --recursive "build"
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The @ sign in filenames in Subversion actually has a special meaning - a pegged revision number. To quote the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html):

> The perceptive reader is probably wondering at this point whether the peg revision syntax causes problems for working copy paths or URLs that actually have at signs in them. After all, how does svn know whether news@11 is the name of a directory in my tree or just a syntax for “revision 11 of news”? Thankfully, while svn will always assume the latter, there is a trivial workaround. You need only append an at sign to the end of the path, such as news@11@. svn cares only about the last at sign in the argument, and it is not considered illegal to omit a literal peg revision specifier after that at sign. This workaround even applies to paths that end in an at sign—you would use filename@@ to talk about a file named filename@.

So, you should append an @ sign to filenames in scripts, like this:

```
svn revert "build\myfile@test.meta@"
```

Comment: Use bhavinb's script below to do this on every file in a directory.  Great script, and great answer Avi.

Comment: This is a problem with iPhone programming because the standard naming convention for images is myimage@2x.png but this workaround works a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Just to add to the above correct answer, if you have lots of files with the "@" symbol in their name that you want to process in a batch (i.e. use * wildcard), you can do something like this in OS X Terminal (or any Linux box really):

```
find . -name "*@*" | xargs -I % svn add %@
```

The above command will use the find utility to list out each file with @ in its filename and then pipe the path to the file to SVN using XARGS. XARGS will replace each occurrence of % with the path and append the special "@" at the end of the filename so that SVN will accept it.

Hope this helps - I had to whack my head for a bit to add the gazzilion @2x.png files that were needed for my app to be upgraded for iOS4.0

Comment: This was a lifesaver. I actually combined it with  svn stat | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add to do svn stat | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % svn add %@

Answer (score 2):

Just tested it properly on windows using the cmd.exe shell - enclosing the name in double quotes works:

```
ctmkx> svn revert "trunk\foo@bar.txt"
Reverted 'trunk\foo@bar.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

What operating system? If it is a *nix system, try quoting your file with 'single@quotes'.

Comment: It's windows. Single quotes do not work - you get output like this:
Skipped ''build'' (i.e. double single quotes)

Comment: @Paulius: Knowing what OS it was in your original question would have been useful.

Comment: also, the single quotes trick doesn't work anyway for this on nix

Comment: @Purrell, good to note, I was thinking there was an issue at the point of the shell parsing the command line.