# How to remove a file with @ in it's name from svn in command line?

Tags: svn

With the new iPhone 2x files i've stumbled uppon this problem...

Comment: What is the problem? Which component rejects the file name? What errors do you get? On what platform?

Comment: similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985203/why-subversion-skips-files-which-contain-the-symbol

Comment: Voting to close as a dupe of @Dmitry's suggestion

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to add a "@" sign in the end to get SVN to process the file.

For example, if you had a file called foo@2x.png which you want to add to SVN, you would type:

```
svn add foo@2x.png@
```

If you have lots of files with the "@" symbol in their name that you want to process in a batch (i.e. use * wildcard), you can do something like this in OS X Terminal:

```
find . -name "*@*" | xargs -I % svn add %@
```

The above command will use the find utility to list out each file with @ in its filename and then pipe **each filepath**  to SVN using XARGS.

For each **filepath**, XARGS will execute the **provided command** `svn add %@`, except that `-I %` tells XARGS to replace each occurrence of "%" in the **provided command**, with the **filepath** piped. XARGS effectively appends the special "@" at the end of the filename.

For example, after replacing the "%" character, XARGS will execute `svn add path/to/your/file@2x.png@`; SVN will accept this (presumably because SVN looks for the **last** occurrence of "@" and treats this as a revision specifier)

Hope this helps - I had to whack my head for a bit to add the gazzilion @2x.png files that were needed for my app to be upgraded for iOS4.0

Comment: Of course, if you want to remove the files instead of adding them, you just need to replace svn add with svn delete in the example above and it should work.

Comment: Nice one. Seems strange though — how come adding an “@” at the end makes this work? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Very strange, I added @ at the end of file name `ubuntu@ec2-54-245-12-20.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com@` and svn delete worked.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I would assume it works because SVN treats the last @ in the string as the revision specifier, so adding one to the end makes it ignore the previous one.

Comment: The solution is described in SVNBook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html