# svn, file listed in rep but can't be deleted

Tags: svn

> svn list

gives

> more-hd.png more@2x.png

That's ok. But I want to remove more@2x.png from the rep. So I

> svn delete more@2x.png

and get

> svn: 'more' does not exist

Huh?

> svn delete "more@2x.png"

and...

> svn: 'more' does not exist

If I just delete the file from my checkout and svn update, the file comes back. I am at a loss how to delete it.

What could this mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511348/how-to-remove-a-file-with-in-its-name-from-svn-in-command-line

Comment: Thanks. SVN is very unintuitive here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Subversion skips files which contain the @ symbol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985203/why-subversion-skips-files-which-contain-the-symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ["Peg and Operative Revisions"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) section of SVNBook.

In your case the command would be `svn delete more@2x.png@`.

> The perceptive reader is probably wondering at this point whether the
>   peg revision syntax causes problems for working copy paths or URLs
>   that actually have at signs in them. After all, how does svn know
>   whether news@11 is the name of a directory in my tree or just a syntax
>   for “revision 11 of news”? Thankfully, while svn will always assume
>   the latter, there is a trivial workaround. You need only append an at
>   sign to the end of the path, such as news@11@. svn cares only about
>   the last at sign in the argument, and it is not considered illegal to
>   omit a literal peg revision specifier after that at sign. This
>   workaround even applies to paths that end in an at sign—you would use
>   filename@@ to talk about a file named filename@.